# XNA: How to restart/restart main Update method?

Tags: c#, memory-management, xna, return, callstack

I am using XNA 4 for an application. I was wondering whether there is a way to abort the processing of the main Update method?

The problem is the following: I am allocating memory in many different places and always check whether this memeory could successfully be reserved. However, if this fails I want to immediately cause the application to enter an alternative Update mode where it e.g. just shows a blue screen informing the user of the problem. I do not want Update to continue as the failed memory allocation could cause unforseen consequences or just throw an exception and crash the application.

At the moment, after every memory allocation I check if it worked, and if it didn't I 'return' the current method. The problem is that this current method can potentially be deep down a complex call stack and to reach the Update() method of XNA I need to 'return' "back up" many other methods which is tedious at best and error prone if a miss any method that e.g. calls a method that calls a method that ... that may fail allocating some memory.

Comment: Just use a flag in some common memory location.

Comment: You could throw a custom exception and not handle it anywhere else other than your update function? Then in the handler just set the flag mentioned above and have an if statement that then determines what update function to use.